# Cannot boot ubuntu 14.04 64 bit via live USB

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

It takes forever to boot, doesn't get past the loading(bootsplash) screen.
i tried few different USB drives and different live USB creator (rufus, unetbootin, pendrivelinux)

more info -

```
Processor - intel i5
ISO image - ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
Laptop    - Dell 3521
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your boot settings, if you have windows 8 you gonna need disable secure & fast boot and activate UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was trying to install the new Ubuntu 14.04.1 from a USB Live, and I tried with the UNetbootin tool, after I reboot my computer I just saw the UNebootin menu but nothing happened.

After that, I tried with the Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator, in another machine, but it doesn't work.

After that I tried with the Universal USB Installer, and it doesn't work.

At the end, I came to windows, and then I formatted my USB with the diskparter tool, with this metod:

Diskpart is a program available in Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8.

Press Windows+R

Write cmd and press Return <<< A windows console will appears.

Write **diskpart** and press Return

It will open a new window, maybe it will ask if you want to execute it like Administrator, and then a new console will appears.

Write: **list disk**

This command will list every storage device connected to the PC.
Take note of wich is your device, because yo can format your PC's hard drive.

And then write: **select disk X** (Where X is your USB device)

After that, you need to type the next commands:

**clean**

**create partition primary**

**format fs=NTFS** >>>>> It is slow, or

**format fs=NTFS quick** >>>>  It is fast!

**assign**

**exit**

After that, I could use the Universal USB Installer, and I could install Ubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems like a very similar problem per your description and was able to resolve the booting to Ubuntu (Live) and also Ubuntu installation problem by adding the `acpi=off` kernel parameter during the LiveCD boot and later adding the `acpi=` parameter as permanent Grub option once Ubuntu had installed. I've detailed the steps I did in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624447/cannot-boot-14-04-ubuntu/634871#634871).

Note that I have some issues yet to resolve -- but at least I now have a functional system to use until that!

Hope this helps.